# COSD and SIND in GFortran 6.3

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Just I have installed gfortran 6.3 in my MacOS.

I'm trying to compile my programs that uses `COSD`, `SIND`, etc., but I have an error message from the compiler.

I have try to use the flag `-fdec-math` in the options of compilation but it doesn't resolve the problem. The compiler gives a message that it is an unknown option.

Also I have tried to use `-std=f2008` but I have the same situation.

What should I do?

Comment: Using `-std=f2008` won't help as `cosd` and `sind` aren't Fortran standard intrinsic functions.  Please show the error message and an [mcve] including the definitions of those procedures.

Comment: Degree functions are not yet supported in any released version. It is only in the current development branch. Is expected in release 7, see [release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/changes.html).

Comment: i guess the docs are ahead of the release? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/COSD.html

Comment: Note that *"This function is for compatibility only and should be avoided in favor of standard constructs wherever possible. "* If the programs are really yours and not legacy than just use standard conforming functions. BTW using `-std=f2008` can actually disable these non-standard functions even in the future version of gfortran.

Comment: You can write your own cosd and sind to satisfy the linker.

Comment: I am not sure how many decades DEC extensions need to be used before they become "conforming functions", but they had a ubiquitous need.

Comment: Yes I can, but I want to say that in manual say that this procedures (COSD,SIND,etc) are available if I use the compiler option -fdec-math and looks that it is incorrect!

Comment: A bunch of goodies are coming to gfortran like MAP and UNION and some other DEC extensions.

Comment: The URL's of the form https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ refer to the current development version. For released versions, the corresponding manual e.g. for version 6.3 is at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.3.0/gfortran/